# basic CRUD in area not working in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have several Areas in my learning/demo app. In 'MyArea/Models' I have 'MyModel.cs'

When I try to add scaffolded item 'MVC controller with Views using EF' everything gets generated, I update database after that, but CRUD operations do not work when I start application. (When I add same Model but not in area everything is fine)

For example, nothing happens when I click link 'create new' on Index.

Can you please help me?

I'm expecting that I can use scaffolding items in ASP.NET Core MVC areas.

/area/partner/models
ticket.cs

```
namespace Website.Areas.Partner.Models
{
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
}
```

/area/partner/controllers/
TicketsController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Website.Areas.Partner.Models;
using Website.Data;

namespace Website.Areas.Partner.Controllers
{
    [Area("Partner")]
    [Authorize]
    public class TicketsController : Controller
    {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public TicketsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Partner/Tickets
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return _context.Ticket != null ?
                    View(await _context.Ticket.ToListAsync()) :
                    Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Ticket'  is null.");
    }

    // GET: Partner/Tickets/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || _context.Ticket == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var ticket = await _context.Ticket
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (ticket == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(ticket);
    }

    // GET: Partner/Tickets/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Partner/Tickets/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title")] Ticket ticket)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(ticket);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(ticket);
    }

    // GET: Partner/Tickets/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || _context.Ticket == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var ticket = await _context.Ticket.FindAsync(id);
        if (ticket == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(ticket);
    }

    // POST: Partner/Tickets/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Title")] Ticket ticket)
    {
        if (id != ticket.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(ticket);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!TicketExists(ticket.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(ticket);
    }

    // GET: Partner/Tickets/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || _context.Ticket == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var ticket = await _context.Ticket
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (ticket == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(ticket);
    }

    // POST: Partner/Tickets/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        if (_context.Ticket == null)
        {
            return Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Ticket'  is null.");
        }
        var ticket = await _context.Ticket.FindAsync(id);
        if (ticket != null)
        {
            _context.Ticket.Remove(ticket);
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool TicketExists(int id)
    {
        return (_context.Ticket?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
    }
}
}
```

/area/partner/views/ticket
index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Website.Areas.Partner.Models.Ticket>

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
<a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-

 id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route- 
 id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

/data/
ApplicationDbContext

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Website.Models;
using Website.Areas.Partner.Models;

namespace Website.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(e => e.FirstName)
                .HasMaxLength(20);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(e => e.LastName)
                .HasMaxLength(30);

        }

        public DbSet<LatestWork> LatestWork { get; set; } = default!;

        public DbSet<Website.Areas.Partner.Models.Ticket> Ticket { get; set; } = default!;

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error messages?

Comment: Could you please share your relevant code snippet? How it look like? Are you following any official document?

Comment: No, I do not see any error message. I can run Application and browse to Area index page, everything is fine until I try to create first row in db. Page is generated because everything is by default, all visual studio code my is only model which I use to generate controller with EF and views.

When application is run and I go to localhost/myarea/mycontroler/index I see empty table (because db is not  seeded) and I see link create new (all defaul VS behavior) but I cannot click link create new, nothing happens when I click on that link.

Comment: I can go manually to  localhost/myarea/mycontroler/create and I see all the fields but row is not saved when I populate data and submit

Comment: When I move model from area and generate code again using same procedure everything is fine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing Tag Helpers in views

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, AuthoringTagHelpers
```